# IntellijIdea plugin - RegexFilter doesn't highlight the line number

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

I have the next issue : in the plugin's console is highlighted only the file name, but not the line. However, when I click on the link, the editor opens the specified file, and the cursor is placed in the specified line :

[image]

The RegexpFilter is initialised in the next way :

```
console.addMessageFilter(new RegexpFilter(project, RegexpFilter.FILE_PATH_MACROS + ":" + RegexpFilter.LINE_MACROS));
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm a little...confused.  What does the picture, the title, and the `RegexpFilter` have to do with each other?  If you say that the cursor is placed on that line, then what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: @Makoto - as you can see in the screen shot, only the file name is highlighted ( looks like a link ). But as the line number is also involved in the position's calculation, I expect it to be part of the link too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design of the `RegexpFilter` implementation, see how the [`highlightEndOffset` is defined](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/execution/filters/RegexpFilter.java#L176).

Line number is not highlighted, only the file path. If you want it to be highlighted as well, create your own `Filter` implementation that will use different logic for the result highlighting.